# Is there a way to have editorconfig settings apply in git automatically when using git add? (using WebStorm)

Tags: git, webstorm, editorconfig

In order to speed up my workflow, I'm wondering if there is a way I can get the EditorConfig settings to apply automatically when I use `git add`. I'm aware that I can save the file or use the shortcut for Code > Reformat Code but was just wondering if I can skip a step.

Thanks!

Comment: You can choose to reformat code in **Commit** dialog, **Before Commit** section - code will be formatted according to `.editorconfig` preferences when commiting

Comment: @lena Sorry for the newbie question, where do I get to the Commit dialog?

Comment: ctrl-k if you are using the default key map.

Comment: you can also add the editor config changes to the code style changes so that when you reformat file(ctrl-shift-l) it formats to the right styling.

Comment: it appears when you choose a **Commit** action from **VCS** main menu or file right-click menu or from the **Version Conrol** tool window. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.1/commit-changes-dialog.html

Answer (score 2):

You can choose to reformat code in **Commit Changes** dialog, **Before Commit** section - code will be formatted according to `.editorconfig` preferences when commiting:

[image]

This dialog is shown  when you choose a **Commit** action (`Ctrl+K` in defult keymap) from the **Version Conrol** tool window, or from **VCS | Git** main menu or file right-click menu. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.1/commit-changes-dialog.html